# What special character might echo be expanding to my home folder?

Tags: shell, wildcards, command-substitution

I was running this single line for:

```
for i in `pwgen -yB -N 8 1`; do echo "$i"; done
```

Then the output is:

```
.
Descargas
Documentos
Escritorio
Imágenes
Música
NetBeansProjects
Plantillas
public_html
Público
Vídeos
.
"
}
"
$
{
```

Some of those, like `Descargas`, `Documentos`, `Escritorio` belongs to my home folder (Which is in Spanish), where I run my cycle.

pwgen with argument `-y` produces at least one special nonalphanumerical character; `-N` param is for selecting the number of generated passwords (8) and the last `1` is for selecting the password lenght (1).

I am wondering which special character can `echo $i` be printing as my home content.

Comment: Maybe `*`? Can't think of anything other than that which would expand to contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
for i in `pwgen -yB -N 8 1`
```

The result of command substitution is subjected to *pathname expansion*.

Do this instead:

```
pwgen -yB -N 8 1 | while IFS= read -r i; do printf '%s\n' "$i"; done
```

#### Example

Observe that `*` appears in the output below, demonstrating that pathname expansion was not performed:

```
$ pwgen -yB -N 8 1 | while IFS= read -r i; do printf '%s\n' "$i"; done
~
-
*
@
;
\
*
-
```

Comment: I don't have `pwgen` so I can't see the original output, but I don't see what the `while read` loop accomplishes at all.  It seems that it would pass through the input unmodified.  What's the point?

Comment: @Wildcard The issue that the OP had was that the shell performed pathname expansion on `*` as it passed through his `for` loop.  The answer here demonstrates that pathname expansion does not happen when using a `while read` loop.  So, yes, the ability of the `while` loop to _"pass through the input unmodified"_ is the point of the answer.

Comment: Okay, but why not just use `pwgen -yB -N 8 1` directly?  Why use any kind of loop at all?

Comment: @Wildcard My interpretation was that the OP was doing some post-processing that failed because of the pathname expansion issue.  He didn't want us to focus on the post-processing; he wanted us to solve the pathname expansion issue.  This is what we recommend to OPs when we ask them to ["create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In this case, the removal of the post-processing was needed to meet the _"minimal"_ criterion.

Comment: @Wildcard I was just trying to perform the `pwgen` command into a cycle for creating passwords for a set of new users. This combination was for nothing special but testing the parameters (I tried a few different), and when I tried this it showed something different from a single special character: my home folder content. I just wondered why.

Thank you for your answer @John1024.

Answer (score 2):

You are using 'split' in `` for i in `command` ``.
But that also comes associated with "File Name Generation" (a.k.a. Pathname Expansion in bash) in which (unquoted) characters like `*`, `?` and `[` are expanded to "file names".

That could be turned off by: `set -f`.

```
set -f ; for i in `pwgen -yB -N 8 1`; do echo "$i"; done
```

---

To use an array might be a good idea:

```
$ set -f; arr=( $(pwgen -yB -N 4 1) ); printf '<%s>\n' "${arr[@]}"
<~>
<&>
<_>
<`>
```

Or perhaps:

```
$ set -f; arr=( $(pwgen -yB -N 5 18) ); printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
oesheisu%ugh>aetas
nae>chootho|yeiwah
quie{thohp+aechuit
ib\iibugeighe<pie?
kie}phah=ngeitaeph
```

---

Of course, you could use readarray to populate the array (no need for `set -f`):

```
$ readarray -t arr < <(pwgen -yB -N 8 1)
```

And then print all elements:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

All in one line:

```
$ readarray -t arr < <(pwgen -yB -N 4 12); printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
ioquavoej&ee
che>u}phoej<
iuchoo"shoom
hahd!eumohsu
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found useful to _"turn off"_ the expansion and the array solution, I didn't know that could be done.

Answer (score 1):

It's `*`:

```
for i in `echo '*'`; do echo "$i"; done
```

How to find it:

```
for i in `pwgen -yB -N 100 1 | tee /tmp/f1`; do echo "$i"; done >/tmp/f2
diff f1 f2
```

You might need to run it several times until you see a difference. Or increase `N`.